# REST API or Azure CLI support for deploying Azure workbook

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor-workbooks

Is there any REST API or dedicated azure CLI commands that can help in the deployment of the workbook.
[Workbook deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-automate) mentions ARM deployment, but maintaining a huge "serializedData" in the arm template is nowhere practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any CLI command for workbook deployment. One easy workaround to your problem is to add a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-parameters) in the ARM template for the serialized data instead of maintaining that in the template itself. Then you can just do a regular [az deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli) using the template and pass your ARM parameter from outside.

Comment: yes, *unfortunately*, the workbook content is that `serializedData` field in the data object of the REST contract.  (and for back compat reasons, that field in workbooks is a string field, so it is *stringified* json in that field!).  

for workbook *templates* (`microsoft.insights/workbooktemplates`), that `serializedData` field is just normal json inline in the contract, it isn't stringified, so its a *little* better there.

At this time we do not have any specialized CLI commands/etc for workbooks.  it is has been requested, and is on our backlog, but unfortunately way down the list.